# How to automate "Clear Generated Data" and "Solve" actions in Ansys WorkBench?

Tags: ansys, ansys-workbench, ansys-apdl

Using Mechanical, there is automation and I can record the process, but what I wanted to do is that for it to first clear the generated data, then proceed with solve (whole model - two steps). It doesn't seems to record these two actions.

I have Command Objects in the model that will generate random data that will tweak some parameters, then export the result to text file in each run. So basically I wanted to automate these two actions within a loop (loop for hundreds of time) using the python scripting.

Any idea for how to achieve this?

Comment: Lots of info if you search: https://blogs.rand.com/randsim/2020/09/automation-in-ansys-mechanical-using-python.html

Comment: You literally saved my day! Thanks so much for pointing to the right direction! I could do `ExtAPI.DataModel.Project.Model.ClearGeneratedData(); ExtAPI.DataModel.Project.Model.Solve()` and that is it! (I've been trying to solve this for two days!!)

Comment: Magic! Have a good day!